# threading can not improve the script speed

Tags: python, multithreading

I will analysis the apache'slog file about 1G.I write a python script,get result about 18 second. 
the script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
name = {}
with open(filename,"r") as data:
    for i in data:
        av = i.split()
        if name.has_key(av[7]):
            name[av[7]] = int(av[4])
        else
            name[av[7]] += int(av[4])


mm = open("ziyou_end","w")
#print result to ziyou_end
for i in name:
    mm.write("%s   %s\n" %(i,name[i]))
```

I will improve the speed of script,then i use threading.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import Queue
import sys
import time
all = {}
def do_work(in_queue, out_queue):
    while True:
        #print 1
        item = in_queue.get()
        #print "item is",item
        #time.sleep(1)
        # process
        aitem = item.split()
        if all.has_key(av[7]):
            all[av[7]] = int(av[4])
        else:
            all[av[7]] += int(av[4])

        #out_queue.put(all)
        #print all
        in_queue.task_done()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    work = Queue.Queue()
    results = Queue.Queue()
    af = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
    #get file
    af_con = []
    for i in af:
        af_con.append(i);

    # start for workers
    for i in xrange(4):
        t = threading.Thread(target=do_work, args=(work, results))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        #start 4 threading

    # produce data
    for i in af_con:
        work.put(i)


    work.join()

    result = open ("result_thread","w");
    # get the results
    for i in all:
        result.write(i+str(all[i])+"\n")

    sys.exit()
```

but it spend 320 second to get the result ,who can tell me ,why

I use multiprocessing is the same ,spent long time get the result

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import os
import time
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1] 
ALL = {}
def process_line(line):
    global ALL
    av = line.split()
    i = av[7]
    if ALL.has_key(i):
       ALL[i] = ALL[i] + int(av[4]) 
    else:
       ALL[i] = int(av[4])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(12)
    with open(filename,"r") as source_file:
        # chunk the work into batches of 4 lines at a time
        results = pool.map(process_line, source_file, 1)
```

I do not know ,why

Comment: Why are you creating a list `data`? That seems completely unnecessary in the single-threaded script.

Comment: Python's threading is notoriously slow, even with the major improvement in the way it handles the GIL in 3.4. You have a better chance trying with multiprocessing over multithreading.

Answer (score 3):

Your task is IO-bound (you spend more time reading the file than processing the data), so threading won't help much, here.

As for your threads, Python only runs on a single core, so threading only helps when there's multiple tasks with blocking IO (like a web server). Instead of having one worker (a core) work on one stack of work, you split the stack into four, but still have the one worker, only now the one worker has to split time between tasks and deal with synchronizing the record keeping.

Try something more like this. It reduces memory overhead (this can improve CPU performance if you're doing a lot of reallocating or allocating and freeing a lot), and eliminates storing the values in a work queue.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

filename = sys.argv[1]
name = defaultdict(int)

with open(filename,"r") as s:
    for i in s:
        av = i.split()
        name[av[7]] += int(av[4])

#print result to ziyou_end    
with open("ziyou_end","w") as mm:
    for k, v in name.iteritems():
        mm.write("%s   %s\n" % (k, v))
```

Comment: Python doesn't run on a single core with multiprocessing though, also you're *certain* that the I/O is the limiting factor here? If the data was on a Fusion I/O card for example, I'd say definitely not.

Comment: Very true; switching from Thread to multiprocessing could improve performance, but it's still largely IO-bound on the file read.

Comment: As for fusion io, you'd need a map-reduce version of this to really take advantage of it.

Comment: I don't think my task is IO-bound,i make a test script:                                                             #!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8
import sys
data=[]
input_file = sys.argv[1] 
with open(input_file,"r") as s:
    for i in s:
        data.append(i)
I got the result use 3 second,I will use multiprocessing to test it

Comment: Also remember that there's time spent writing your output file. It's kinda unusual for the computation you're doing to be expensive. Unless your int gets promoted to a long, this is all pretty fast.